# How to add new column to csv rows by calculating date difference

Tags: python-3.x

Below is sample input csvrows. Assuming A,B,C,D are people with their date of birth and date they passed away. A and C are deceased. B and D are still alive. I need to sort the people with their date of birth and calculate their age(in years) as a new column. For people still alive, calculate using today's date. For deceased people, calculate their age on the day they passed away.

```
A,20020215,20190217
B,20010219,
C,20150217,20180315
D,20100216,
```

Comment: Have you already imported the CSV data to a dataframe (Pandas, for example)?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed walk through with comments, Kris. I probably should have mentioned in my question, actually need to accomplish this without pandas.

Comment: I’ll be at my desk in about an hour and will help with a new solution. How are you storing the data once in python?

Comment: Data is stored in a list called csvrows with each row as a string, which is called in a function, something like def functionname(csvrows)

Comment: I updated to add a solution without Pandas. Give it a try and let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: did any of the ideas below answer your question? If not, please update so we can help you further. If so, please mark the question as 'answered' so that the others can see the solution you accepted.

Comment: Thanks Kris. Appreciate your time in revisiting. Might you be able to help me, How can i get better at working with files in python ? Any tips would be great.

Comment: Happy to help out @Naren. I'd recommend starting with this link to get a hang of working with files: https://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse231/Online/files1.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Is there a way i can connect with you, perhaps LinkedIn or email.

Comment: my LinkedIn is linked via my bio. Feel free to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with importing the CSV, and then walk through each step I used for your sample data:

```
# import data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
fp = "your directory to csv file"
df = pd.read_csv(fp, dtype=str)

# clean data (change to dates)
df['BIRTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BIRTH']).dt.date
df['DEATH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DEATH']).dt.date

# Calculate the delta and convert to years, rounded to 1 decimal point
curdate = dt.datetime.today().date() # grabs current date for AGE calculation
df.loc[df['DEATH'].notnull(), 'AGE'] = df['DEATH'] - df['BIRTH'] # death listed
df.loc[df['DEATH'].isnull(), 'AGE'] = curdate - df['BIRTH'] # no death listed
df['AGE'] = round(df['AGE']/np.timedelta64(1,'Y'),1)
df.head()
```

[image: Pandas Result]
also note: I named my columns in a mockup CSV as: ID, BIRTH, and DEATH. These names should be changed in the script to match your column names.

EDIT / UPDATE: NON-PANDAS SOLUTION

```
# input
csvrows = ['A,20020215,20190217', 'B,20010219,', 'C,20150217,20180315', 'D,20100216,']

# define function for adding Age

from datetime import datetime as dt

def AddAge(csvlist):
    ## Input: list of ID, BIRTH DATE, DEATH DATE, ie: 
    ##     A,20020215,20190217
    ##     B,20010219,
    ##     C,20150217,20180315
    ##     D,20100216,

    ## Returns: list of ID, BIRTH DATE, DEATH DATE, AGE AT TIME OF DEATH *OR* CURRENT AGE

    # amend list (split on ",")
    temp = [i.split(',') for i in csvrows]

    # add current date where date of death missing
    for idx, el in enumerate(temp):
        if el[-1] == "":
            el[-1] = dt.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

    # convert values to datetime
        temp[idx] = [el[0], dt.strptime(el[1], '%Y%m%d'), dt.strptime(el[2], '%Y%m%d')]

    # calculate age 
        delta = temp[idx][2] - temp[idx][1]
        temp[idx].append(str(round(delta.days / 365.25, 1)))

    # reformat times
        temp[idx][1] = str(el[1])
        temp[idx][2] = str(el[2])   

    # return string to original format, eliminating the earlier split
    s = ','
    returnlist = [s.join(i) for i in temp]

    # return list
    return returnlist
```

[image: Non Pandas Result]

ONE FINAL EDIT: You may not want the current date returned in the 'date of death' position. To amend:

```
def AddAge(csvlist):
    ## Input: list of ID, BIRTH DATE, DEATH DATE, ie: 
    ##     A,20020215,20190217
    ##     B,20010219,
    ##     C,20150217,20180315
    ##     D,20100216,

    ## Returns: list of ID, BIRTH DATE, DEATH DATE, AGE AT TIME OF DEATH *OR* CURRENT AGE

    # amend list (split on ",")
    temp = [i.split(',') for i in csvrows]

    for idx, el in enumerate(temp):

    # calculate age 
        if el[-1] == "":
            temp[idx] = [el[0], dt.strptime(el[1], '%Y%m%d'), el[2]]
            delta = dt.today() - temp[idx][1]
        else:
            temp[idx] = [el[0], dt.strptime(el[1], '%Y%m%d'), dt.strptime(el[2], '%Y%m%d')]
            delta = temp[idx][2] - temp[idx][1]
        temp[idx].append(str(round(delta.days / 365.25, 1)))

    # reformat times to string
        temp[idx][1] = str(el[1])
        temp[idx][2] = str(el[2])

    # return string to original format, eliminating the earlier split
    s = ','
    returnlist = [s.join(i) for i in temp]

    # return list
    return returnlist
```

[image: Non Pandas Result 2]